# Mocha and chai test for registration should not insert into DB

Tags: node.js, express, testing, mocha.js, chai

I am writing tests for an API built with Node and Express. I am trying to test the registration route using mocha and chai. But the test data for registration inserts into the database, which I don't want.

Is it possible to test registration and make sure it works without the dummy data inserting into the database?

Or better, how can I hook up the testing to a different database?

Thank you.

Just incase, here is the code for my test

```
describe('AUTH ROUTES', () => {
describe('POST /api/v1/auth/register', () => {
    const correctUser = {
        firstName: 'test',
        lastName: 'test',
        email: 'test@test.com',
        password: '111'
    };

    const wrongUser = {
        lastName: 'test',
        password: '111'
    };

    it('It should REGISTER a user when complete detail is received', (done) => {
        chai
            .request(server)
            .post('/api/v1/auth/register')
            .send(correctUser)
            .end((err, res) => {
                res.should.have.status(SUCCESS_CODE);
                res.body.should.be.a('object');
                res.body.should.have.property('success').eq(true);
                done();
            });
    });

    it('It should NOT REGISTER a user when incomplete detail is received', (done) => {
        chai
            .request(server)
            .post('/api/v1/auth/register')
            .send(wrongUser)
            .end((err, res) => {
                res.should.have.status(BAD_REQUEST.code);
                res.body.should.be.a('object');
                res.body.should.have.property('errors');
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use afterEach function to drop the table after you run your beforeEach test.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can stub every response given by your controller.